# pandas: how to avoid iterating through rows when you need to verify the data sequentially?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which is composed of a timestamp and two variables:

1. A pressure measurement which varies sequentially, representing a specific process batch (in red);
2. An lab analysis, which represents a measurement that represents each batch. The analysis always occurs at the end of the batch and remains a constant value until a new analysis is made. Caution: not every batch is analyzed and I don't have a flag indicating when the batch started.

I need to create a dataframe which calculates, for each batch, the average, maximum and minimum temperature, and how long it took from start to end (timedelta).

I had an idea to loop through all analysis values from the end to the start, and every time I find a new analysis value OR the pressure dropped below a certain value (since this is a characteristic of the process, all batches starts with low pressure), I'd consider as the batch start (to calculate the timedelta and to define the interval I would consider for taking the pressure min, max, and average).

However, I know it is not effective to loop through all dataframe rows (especially with 1 million rows) so, any ideas?

Dataset sample: https://cl1p.net/5sg45sf5 or https://wetransfer.com/downloads/321bc7dc2a02c6f713963518fdd9271b20201115195604/08c169

Edit: there is no clear/ready indication of when a batch starts in the current data (as someone asked), but you can identify a batch by the following characteristics:

1. Every batch starts with pressure below 30 and going up fastly (in less than one hour) up to  61.
2. Then it stabilizes around 65 (the plateau value can be something between 61 and 70) and stays there for at least 2 and a half hours.
3. It ends with a pressure drop (faster than one hour) to a value smaller than 30.
4. The cycle repeats.
   OBS: you can have smaller/shorter peaks between two valid batches, but it shall not be considered as a batch.

Thanks!

Comment: please post your data as a dataframe, not an image.

Comment: how do you segment/define a batch?

Comment: Does each batch start when the lab analysis value changes?

Comment: the lab analysis marks the "end" of the batch. The batch starts with a low pressure value, unfortunately I have no other indicator to signalize it.

Comment: @anon01 , I did posted the dataframe. Both links contains a text file with it.

Comment: The biggest problem I am finding is just identifying when a batch changes. If a batch change only occurs when the lab analysis changes, then I can give you a solution

Comment: Yes, that's my struggle also. If I had a flag informing when each batch started, I could use a groupby.agg and done. Was that your idea also? I'll try to figure out something and let you know if I get any other ideas...

Comment: @jlb_gouveia, do you think you could look my edited post please? :) I put some more information as you asked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes that the batches change when the value of `lab analysis` changes.
First, I'll plot those changes, so we can get an idea of how frequently it does:

```
df['lab analysis'].plot()
```

[image]

There are not many changes, so we just need to identify these:

```
df_shift = df.loc[(df['lab analysis'].diff()!=0) & (df['lab analysis'].diff().isna() == False)]
df_shift

        time                pressure    lab analysis
2632    2020-09-15 19:52:00 356.155     59.7
3031    2020-09-16 02:31:00 423.267     59.4
3391    2020-09-16 08:31:00 496.583     59.3
4136    2020-09-16 20:56:00 625.494     59.4
4971    2020-09-17 10:51:00 469.114     59.2
5326    2020-09-17 16:46:00 546.989     58.9
5677    2020-09-17 22:37:00 53.730      59.0
6051    2020-09-18 04:51:00 573.789     59.2
6431    2020-09-18 11:11:00 547.015     58.7
8413    2020-09-19 20:13:00 27.852      58.5
10851   2020-09-21 12:51:00 570.747     58.9
15816   2020-09-24 23:36:00 553.846     58.7
```

Now we can run a loop from these few changes, categorize each batch, and then run the descriptive statistics:

```
index_shift = df_shift.index
i = 0
batch = 1
for shift in index_shift:
    df.loc[i:shift, 'batch number'] = batch
    batch = batch + 1
    i = shift

stats = df.groupby('batch number')['pressure'].describe()[['mean','min','max']]
```

And compute the time difference and insert on stats as well:

```
df_shift.loc[0] = df.iloc[0,:3]
df_shift.sort_index(inplace = True)
time_difference = [*df_shift['time'].diff()][1:]
stats['duration'] = time_difference

stats

                mean        min     max      duration
batch number                
1.0             518.116150  24.995  671.315  1 days 19:52:00
2.0             508.353105  27.075  670.874  0 days 06:39:00
3.0             508.562450  26.715  671.156  0 days 06:00:00
4.0             486.795097  25.442  672.548  0 days 12:25:00
5.0             491.437620  24.234  671.611  0 days 13:55:00
6.0             515.473651  29.236  671.355  0 days 05:55:00
7.0             509.180860  25.566  670.714  0 days 05:51:00
8.0             490.876639  25.397  671.134  0 days 06:14:00
9.0             498.757555  24.973  670.445  0 days 06:20:00
10.0            497.000796  25.561  670.667  1 days 09:02:00
11.0            517.255608  26.107  669.476  1 days 16:38:00
12.0            404.859498  20.594  672.566  3 days 10:45:00
```

Comment: Thanks, @jlb_gouveia. The suggestion is nice but the assumption does not apply. I'm trying to find out a way to use some kind of pattern identification, because the real challenge here is precisely that we do not have a clear indication of each batch's start.

Comment: Without a clear rule I can't help much, also given I don't know the subject well to tell whether a fall of 50% (for example) of pressure will represent a change in batch or not. 

But, for a final suggestion, you can do `df['pressure].pct_change()` to get the percentage changes. Check the statistics on the percentage changes, and maybe you'll be able to define a threshold for batch change. If the threshold becomes a 50% fall, then you can find the shifts by doing the following: `df.loc[df['pressure'].pct_change() < -0.5]`.

Comment: I added some details regarding how to identify a batch. Do you think you could maybe check if this information would be enough? I don't know why this question got downvoted :/